# How do I use memory sharing correctly in c#.Net 4?

Tags: c#, memory, .net-4.0, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I don't know if it's because of old posts or just lack of understanding but I seem to be coming across all kinds of bad info when it comes to using memory maps in .Net4.  Maybe as soon as .Net4 was released in beta everyone started posting about it and things were different in .Net4 beta?  Or maybe I just don't know what I'm talking about and they are all right but I can't seem to figure out the correct way to use memory maps.  I'm looking for a way to use the same code on BOTH apps so the code is generic and one of the two apps would not be considered a primary (that creates something the other app needs).  Example 1 is a prime example of the idea I DO NOT want to achieve (it's just there as an example of what I've found).

In the end I want both apps to run over and over again accessing a memory stream (memory map) to read and write data as it needs to.  When the last app using the memory map is exiting the map should be closed and deleted.

I have seen the following examples trying to show how to correctly use memory maps.  I don't know what they are all doing but the overloads they are using seem to be wrong too.  :/

### Example 1:

This would be used on app1.exe where the memory is first created.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFile;

MemoryMappedFile MemoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(
  new FileStream(@"C:\temp\Map.mp", FileMode.Create),
  "MyMemMapFile",
  1024 * 1024,
  MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite
);

//Write to the memory map
MemoryMappedViewAccessor FileMapView = MemoryMapped.CreateViewAccessor();
int Number = 1234;

FileMapView.Write(0, Number);
FileMapView.Write<Container>(4, ref MyContainer);
```

This would be used on app2.exe where the memory is accessed later.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFile;

MemoryMappedFile MemoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(
  new FileStream(
    @"C:\temp\Map.mp",
    FileMode.Create),
  "MyMemMapFile",
  1024 * 1024,
  MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite
);

// Create the map view and read it
using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor FileMap = MemoryMapped.CreateViewAccessor())
{
  Container NewContainer = new Container();
  FileMap.Read<Container>(4, out NewContainer);
}
```

### Example 2:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FileStream file = File.OpenRead("Test.cs");
        using (MemoryMappedFile mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile
               (file, "PEIMAGE", file.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var viewStream = mappedFile.CreateViewStream
                   (0, file.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
            {
                // read from the view stream
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you worried about something specific?

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that the examples are dead wrong now.  I just wanted someone to answer with code that shows me what snippet I can place in both app1.exe and app2.exe to say, share a structure I made.  How do I need to determine the amount of memory needed, how do I need to open the memory map file (can i just use CreateOrOpen instead of ever using CreateFromFile), etc.  But I just want someone to show me an example of it now, in 2016.  ;)

Comment: The examples do not do what you need but I would not call them dead wrong. Even if the "overloads are wrong", which I do not know, fixing that should not be too difficult. It is hard to answer without more context about what you want to achieve. Is this supposed to become an IP mechanism? Maybe use named pipes.

Comment: When I say `"These examples are dead wrong"` that means they are simply NOT correct and will not compile.  I'm 100% telling you that the overloads being used in the examples are incorrect.  I don't see what is so hard about answering my question.  I simply wanted an example of how to properly use memory sharing between two applications in a very specific way.  I thought I made it very clear what I was trying to get in an answer.  It's all moot anyway, I just posted an answer I came up with just trying different things and digging into more research.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. The best questions are about specific problems. Providing sample code when it is not clear what's unclear to the OP is not something most people are willing to do (because it's boring and often misses the point of the question).

Comment: Here, I didn't see what's so hard about "fixing the overloads". It seems you just need to go to the MSDN documentation and pick an appropriate overload. Looks like you did that meanwhile. As long as I didn't understand why you couldn't "simply" do that I was not going to post an answer.

Comment: Looking back at your comments/questions I see where you might have gotten confused when you asked `Is this supposed to become an IP mechanism?`.  This in no way was intended for that.  I think you figured that from my variable names maybe?  I used the term `packet` just to describe the "packet" of data in bytes.  Sorry for the misleading variable names, this was just simply intended on passing data from one app to another.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bunch of research elsewhere, trying to weed out the old code that is incorrect from over the years (back in the .Net4 beta days) I managed to come up with the following.  This gives a basic great example of how to handle the memory map, memory view streams, read method, and write method.  In this example I also use a user defined structure to pass data from one application to the other.

**How To Use This In Application #1 (write)**

Say we wanted application #1 to write some data to the memory stream.  In the Form_Load AFTER connecting to the memory stream just use something like the following...

```
UpdateInfoPacket packet = new UpdateInfoPacket();
packet.JobName = "This is my test job.";
packet.NumberOfFiles = 40;
packet.Status = 'F';
WriteMemoryMap(packet);
```

**How To Use This In Application #2 (read)**

Say we wanted application #2 to read some data from the memory stream.  In the Form_Load AFTER connecting to the memory stream just use something like the following...

```
UpdateInfoPacket packet;
ReadMemoryMap(out packet);
```

### Complete Solution

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyMemoryApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private struct UpdateInfoPacket
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
            public string JobName;

            public char Status;

            public int NumberOfFiles;
        }

        private MemoryMappedFile m_memMap = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_memMap = ConnectToMemoryMap("MyMemoryMapName");
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_memMap != null) m_memMap.Dispose();
        }

        private MemoryMappedFile ConnectToMemoryMap(string mapName)
        {
            MemoryMappedFile memMap = null;
            try
            {
                memMap = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(mapName);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message != "Unable to find the specified file.")
                {
                    //BIG ERROR, report it
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error " + ex.Message);
                }
                memMap = null;
            }

            //Create the memory map if needed
            try
            {
                if (memMap == null)
                    memMap = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(mapName, 10000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //BIG ERROR, report it
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error " + ex.Message);

                memMap = null;
            }

            return memMap;
        }

        private int PacketSize()
        {
            UpdateInfoPacket packet = new UpdateInfoPacket();
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(packet);
            return size;
        }

        private byte[] PacketToBytes(UpdateInfoPacket packet)
        {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(packet);
            byte[] array = new byte[size];

            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(packet, ptr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, array, 0, size);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return array;
        }

        private UpdateInfoPacket BytesToPacket(byte[] packet)
        {
            UpdateInfoPacket structure = new UpdateInfoPacket();

            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

            Marshal.Copy(packet, 0, ptr, size);

            structure = (UpdateInfoPacket)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, structure.GetType());
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

            return structure;
        }

        private void ReadMemoryMap(out UpdateInfoPacket packet)
        {
            packet = new UpdateInfoPacket();

            MemoryMappedViewStream memStream = null;
            try
            {
                //Make sure there is a map first
                if (m_memMap == null) return;

                //Create the view stream
                memStream = m_memMap.CreateViewStream();
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //Create the object to read from the memory map
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(memStream))
                {
                    //Read the data from memory in bytes
                    byte[] rawPacket = reader.ReadBytes(PacketSize());

                    //Convert the byte data to the structure
                    if (rawPacket != null) packet = BytesToPacket(rawPacket);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //BIG ERROR, report it
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void WriteMemoryMap(UpdateInfoPacket packet)
        {
            MemoryMappedViewStream memStream = null;
            try
            {
                //Make sure there is a map first
                if (m_memMap == null) return;

                //Create the view stream
                memStream = m_memMap.CreateViewStream();
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //Create the object to write to the memory map
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memStream))
                {
                    //Convert the structure to a byte array
                    byte[] rawPacket = PacketToBytes(packet);

                    //Write the byte array to memory
                    writer.Write(rawPacket);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //BIG ERROR, report it
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```